# Using information/result from a command in OS X terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, console

I'm writing a shell script on OS X and I don't know how to reuse the returned values and save them as variables. For example, if I enter command "git submodule foreach --recursive" inside of terminal I get printed 3 lines, like so:

```
Entering 'path/of/submodule/1'
Entering 'path/of/submodule/2'
Entering 'path/of/submodule/3'
```

Now I want to use these paths Strings for further manipulation inside my script. So I need to save them in something like maybe an Array.... ??? This is first time I'm trying to shell scripts so any suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical approach would be to feed stdout to a while loop:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive \
  | while read line ; do
       echo Processing $line
       ...
    done
```

To strictly answer your question, you can also assign the result of a command to a variable with

```
a=$(git submodule foreach --recursive)
```

If you want `a` to be an array, use

```
a=($(git submodule foreach --recursive))
```

BUT bash tends to split on white space so you need to be careful when using that syntax on strings that contain spaces and you expect a split at newlines.

If your objective is simply to process the output one line at a time, the `while` is the most straightforward one.